How should you split up data in a train-test-validation split
I've seen it is generally recommended when using a train-test-validation data split, to first split your data into train and test datasets, and then furtherly split the train dataset into a train and validation dataset. It is not recommended to split into train and test datasets, and then split the test dataset into test and validation datasets. I suppose this has something to do with preventing data leakage, but I'm not fully sure. Why is this the case?
Currently, I'm working on a multilabel CNN model to predict tags of video-games based on screenshots, where I will have ~400 classes (tags) as outputs (one video-game can have multiple tags). For the least frequent classes, there are only ~10 instances. I am going to perform a stratified train-test split on the data to maintain class proportions (although this is somewhat difficult due to covariation of classes), and I am worried if I furtherly split up the train dataset, this may lead to some classes in the test or validation sets to not appear in the train dataset. Would it be valid in this case to instead split the test dataset into test and validation sets?
Any clarity on either of these questions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

where did you read this claim? I'm pretty sure that is literally the same, if train-test-val data come from the same dataset and there are no a-priori splits

Yes I couldn't see how the two methods could differ. It was recommended to subsplit the train set in this blog (https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2023/11/train-test-validation-split/#:~:text=the%20following%20aspects%3A-,Training%2C%20Validation%2C%20and%20Testing,model's%20performance%20on%20new%20data.) and a few forums I found explicitly advised against subsplitting the test set (such as this one: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/102463/how-do-i-split-correctly-split-my-dataset-into-train-test-and-validation), but could not find an explanation for the claim.

Split sample validation requires about 20,000 cases to be reliable/stable if the outcome variable is binary.  There is too much "luck of the split" involved.  That's why resampling validation is so popular.  Detailed discussion may be found here.

Okay, thanks for this @FrankHarrell, good to know. I was initially considering employing stratified k fold validation, but would I be correct in saying a resampling validation method such as this is much more computationally costly? I am working with over 125,000 screenshots, and don't know how well my computer would take it . (The link above is not working for me, but I believe this is the page you were referencing: link)

If you have 125k independent samples you could probably do split-sample validation and save a lot of time.  Hard to figure the split fractions but you might think about 50k validation sample and the rest for training.  If using cross-validation with smaller samples I’d do 100 repeats of 10-fold cv.

Great, thanks for the help!
